# Javascript İf Promise Loaded Onclick Then İf Again Onclick Dont Load Again?

Tags: javascript, promise

```
var sarki = document.getElementsByClassName("sarki")[0];
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

sarki.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementsByClassName("siyah")[0].innerHTML = "<div class='loader'></div>";
Promise.all([
  fetch('blabla.txt').then(x => x.text())
]).then(([sarki]) => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("siyah")[0].innerHTML = sarki;
}),modal.style.display = "block",document.title="blabla";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none",document.title="blabla";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none",document.title="blabla";
  }
}
```

As you can see if button clicked promise will get txt file but again as you can see i open modal and you can close that modal but if you again click that button(without refresh page) that txt file will loaded again... İ just want to check if txt file loaded then dont load again because i make song list but if that loaded again playing song is stopping...

How can i do if file loaded dont load it again with javascript(without library) ?

Comment: Did it occur to you to set a variable to true if the txt file when the txt file has been initially fetch, and then don't subsequently perform the fetch?

Comment: İf i understand you correct yes i want to be if txt file loaded true dont load again else if txt file not loaded load it... (sorry to my bad English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track whether or not the text file has yet been loaded. You also don't need `Promise().all()`, since you're dealing with a single factor (the file), not multiple.

```
let file; //<-- file loaded tracker
sarki.onclick = function () {
    let prom = new Promise(res => {
        !file ?
            fetch('blabla.txt').then(x => res(file = x.text())) :
            res(file);
    });
    prom.then(file => {
        document.getElementsByClassName("siyah")[0].innerHTML = file;
    });
}
```

Comment: İ tryed that code but when i close modal and again click button that txt file will load again... So my problem is not solved :(

Comment: No, it won't. Check the network console. It loads the file once, then reads from the cache variable, `file`, subsequent times.

Comment: No, cache the Promise not its payload. Otherwise a quick second click on sarki will find `file` still to be falsy and a second fetch will be initiated ... unnecessarily. Caching the Promise, on the other hand, allows the cache to be set synchronously, on first click and there's no chance that a subsequent click will find `file` still undefined.